# Issue loading phpmailer 6.0

Tags: php, namespaces, phpmailer

Having problem with upgrading phpMailer 5.xx to 6.0. Used several versions of phpmailer for years, no problems like this. I prefer to not use composer.

From upgrade guide "Alternatively, if you're not using composer, copy the contents of the PHPMailer folder into one of the include_path directories specified in your PHP configuration and load each one manually." I prefer to not modify the include_path file on a shared host.

I used the PHPMailerAutoload.php for my 5.xx versions

I used this from the 6.0 package:
"Upgrading from PHPMailer 5.2 to 6.0
If you're not using composer, you can still load the classes manually, depending on what you're using:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
```

No errors reported on these

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found in ///path to my code

Tried `$mail = new \PHPMailer(true);`

Tried lower case file names for `PHPMailer.php` and `SMTP.php`

Tried `class.PHPMailer.php` and `class.SMTP.php`; and with lowercase filenames

Answer (score 2):

Look at [the examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/6.0/examples) for reference - you need to either `use` a namespaced class or reference it absolutely, for example:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

or

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer(true);
```

As came to light in [your github ticket for the same question](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/959), `use` statements only apply in the file in which they are defined (see [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)), and so your split into two files (which you didn't mention initially) breaks it. You have them split like this; in the first file:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
```

and in the second file:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

The `use` statements do not apply to the second file, so the class is indeed undefined, though the `require`s are still valid as they are global. You need to split it like this:

```
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
```

and:

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
```

For further info on upgrading to 6.0, read [the upgrade guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/6.0/UPGRADING.md).

Comment: For those who are migrating to PHPMailer from 5.x to 6.x and prefer to not use composer [I find it troublesome on a shared host], here is my simple result per Synchro's help. At the top of my functions file [code]require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/PHPMailer.php';//MAILER_DIR defined in config
require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/SMTP.php';
require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/Exception.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;// these must be here for pHPMailer 6+ Also, 3 or 4 functions use these, so put here instead of in the functions
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

Comment: That's covered in the upgrade guide - I added a link to my answer.

Comment: For those migrating to PHPMailer from 5.x to 6.x and prefer to not use composer [I find it troublesome on a shared host], here is my simple result per Synchro's help. At the top of my functions file `require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/PHPMailer.php';//MAILER_DIR defined in config require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/SMTP.php'; require_once MAILER_DIR .'/src/Exception.php'; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;// these must be here for pHPMailer 6+ Also, 3 or 4 functions use these, so put here instead of in the functions use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP; use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;`

Comment: If you can't run composer on your host, just run it locally and then upload your vendor folder.